# How to upload Image on Android?

Tags: android, image, upload

I havve to upload image from my SD card to PHP server. I have read a lot of articles and topics but I have some problems...

First I have use that code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    //DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    String urlServer = hostName+"Upload";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    String serverResponseMessage;
    //int serverResponseCode;

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {

        showLog("uploading file: " + file);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pictureFileDir+"/"+file) );

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Set HTTP method to POST.
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + file +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        //serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

        showLog("server response: " + serverResponseMessage);

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but server response 200/OK and no file was on destination server...

After i have read about Multipart:

```
try {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params); 
        File image = new File(pictureFileDir + "/" + filename);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(hostName+"Upload");

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
        multipartEntity.addPart("Image", new FileBody(image));
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

        mHttpClient.execute(httppost, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but then a i have such LOG in LogCat and nothing else...

> 06-04 06:50:52.277: D/dalvikvm(1584): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;.INSTANCE
>   06-04 06:50:52.277: W/dalvikvm(1584): VFY: unable to resolve static field 6688 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;
>   06-04 06:50:52.277: D/dalvikvm(1584): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001b

ServerSide Script:

```
$target_path  = "uploads";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['Image']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

why? What is the simplest way to upload image?

Comment: well I got one question: where is the code of your server? how will it process the file?

Comment: ok i have edited my question with ServerSide Code

Comment: Try this working solution it works perfectly for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24013495/3561701

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the [httpmime](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime) and [httpcore](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore) libraries for this code.

Then, do this:

```
try {
    MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    File file = new File(YOUR_ABSOLUTE_PATH_STRING);

    if (!file.exists())
        return null;

    mBuilder.addPart("mFile", new FileBody(file));
}

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(YOUR_SERVER_URL);
httpPost.setEntity(mBuilder.build());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

//Reading the response:
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(line + "\n");

is.close();
httpEntity.consumeContent();
//Do something with the string returned: sb.toString()

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

PHP Code

```
$fileName = uniqid() . ".png";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mFile"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $fileName))
    return $fileName;
return "";
```

This code works for me, so if it doesn't work for you - check the image path you're sending, try a different image etc.

Comment: I already have those libraries and always get LogCat message: 06-04 09:36:17.423: D/dalvikvm(2226): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;.INSTANCE
06-04 09:36:17.423: W/dalvikvm(2226): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3558 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;
06-04 09:36:17.423: D/dalvikvm(2226): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001b

Comment: Are the libraries also included in the java buildpath? (do they appear under Android Private Libraries). Also, make sure you're not accidently using the desktop versions of these two libraries

Comment: yes they apper under Android Private Libraries... "desktop version"? there is only HttpClient for desktop and android but i can't see mime and core libraries specially for android [link](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Comment: The links in my post are for the android version of the required libraries. Can you try to replace the existing jars with the ones from the links, just to be sure this isn't the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it is also using multipart, it worked for me.

```
try {
    String url = "<destination-path>";
    String fileName = ""; //file to be uploaded
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    FileBody fileContent = new FiSystem.out.println("hello");
    StringBody comment = new StringBody("Filename: " + fileName);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileContent);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
}
```

Comment: I have the same LOG in LogCat like I have written before... What kind of library do you use? org.apache.http or something else?

Answer (score 0):

OK finally everything work :) I have used that code:

```
try {
    showLog("uploading file: " + file);
    File image = new File(pictureFileDir + "/" + file);

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(image);

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Set HTTP method to POST.
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pictureFileDir + "/" + file + "\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    //serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    showLog("server response: " + serverResponseMessage);

    image.delete();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

and PHP script:

```
$target_path  = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
} 
else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Thanks everyone :)